# Getting JSONDecodeError while loading json string

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load json object received in request as:

```
bounds = '{"south_west": {"lat":37.315283,"lng": -122.027188},"north_east": {"lat": 37.321571, "lng": -122.016354}}}'
```

`json.loads(js)` is throwing error as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e98e162e3c87> in <module>
----> 1 json.loads(js)
      2 

~/GoogleDrive/beans-home/mount_shared_partition/conda_envs/solaris/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~/GoogleDrive/beans-home/mount_shared_partition/conda_envs/solaris/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
--> 340             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    341         return obj
    342 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 106 (char 105)
```

I have tried to replace double quotes with single quotes but no avail.

any help?

Comment: Remove one curly bracket at the end.

Comment: How did you create the JSON in the first place? Use a proper JSON encoder and you'll always get valid JSON.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly where the problem is: character 106. Which is the last `}` character.